# Django orm is creating a copy of instance instead of accessing it

Tags: python, django, namespaces, django-orm

I have I think kind of a tricky question in Django and it's orm.

**This does not work :**

```
cartitemproduct_in_cart_session.get().quantity+=1

cartitemproduct_in_cart_session.get().save()
```

If I check just after that the value of cartitemproduct_in_cart_session.get().quantity, it wasn't updated

**This works** :

```
cartitem_session=cartitemproduct_in_cart_session.get()

cartitem_session.quantity+=1

cartitem_session.save()
```

The value was updated

**But why ?**

(cartitemproduct_in_cart_session is a queryset, result of a filter, but I think it doesn't matter : `cartitemproduct_in_cart_session=cart_session.cartitem_set.filter(product__slug=cartitem.product.slug`) )

I am guessing that somehow, when I do cartitemproduct_in_cart_session.get().quantity, the field quantity becomes a new attributes of cartitemproduct_in_cart_session.get() and isn't linked anymore to the field in the database, but I don't understand why ...

**Why do you need to first assign an instance of a model to a name, in order to update the fields of that instance ?**

Comment: When you do `cartitemproduct_in_cart_session.get().save()` you get the object and save it again. Any changes that you did to a different instance of the object don't matter. This is like `cartitem_session=cartitemproduct_in_cart_session.get()` followed by `cartitem_session.save()`.

Comment: Each time you call `cartitemproduct_in_cart_session.get()` it fetches a new instance. You need to fetch the instance once, assign it to a variable, update the field value, then save the same instance that you fetched. By instance I mean in the Python/ OOP sense (https://www.pythonlikeyoumeanit.com/Module4_OOP/ClassInstances.html) and not row in the database

Comment: Thanks a lot you two ! It was simplier than i though ...
In fact i was thinking that cartitemproduct_in_cart_session.get() was creating a kind of link with the database, but i was totally wrong ...
In fact, the call just create an instance in Python, then there in python you can totally modify this instance, and when you call save() on that instance, the totality of the instance is copied back again in the database ...
So, as you say, there is no link between the instance in Python and the row in the database, and what is important is the object in memory in python ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> cartitemproduct_in_cart_session.get().quantity+=1
>
> cartitemproduct_in_cart_session.get().save()

is equivalent to:

```
x = cartitemproduct_in_cart_session.get()
x.quantity += 1

y = cartitemproduct_in_cart_session.get()
y.save()
# note that x and y are different objects with different memory addresses
```

while

> cartitem_session=cartitemproduct_in_cart_session.get()
>
> cartitem_session.quantity+=1
>
> cartitem_session.save()

is equivalent to:

```
x = cartitemproduct_in_cart_session.get()
x.quantity += 1
x.save()
```

Comment: Thanks a lot ! It was simplier than i though ...
In fact i was thinking that x = cartitemproduct_in_cart_session.get() was creating a kind of link with the database, but i was totally wrong ...
In fact, the call just create an instance in Python, then there in python you can totally modify this instance, and when you call x.save(), the totality of the instance is copied back again in the database ...
So, as you say, there is no link between the instance in Python and the row in the database, and what is important is the object in memory in python ...

Comment: https://www.sankalpjonna.com/learn-django/save-your-django-models-using-update-fields-for-better-performance  helps a lot to understand, it illustrates what save() does internally (in SQL)